# Problems with basic for loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'm trying out a super basic for loop in PowerShell and I keep getting errors. Here is my loop:

```
for ($x = 1: $x -le 5: $x++) {

Write-Host $x

}
```

I get the error message: 1: : The term '1:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Can I not use 1? Whats the issue?

Comment: `:` -> `;` or ``function 1: {"1`n2`n3`n4`n5"}``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What he is trying to say, you have a typo, it should be:

```
for ($x = 1; $x -le 5; $x++) {

Write-Host $x

}
```

Comment: Yep, this was the issue. The online book I'm using doesn't have great resolution, so I saw : instead of ;